# Telegram Bots sendPhoto Error

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I can use `sendPhoto` method in telegram bots `API` and it sends photos successfully, but usually the photos that are submitted to the bot beforehand. However when I try to send that photos with another bot (using the same `file_id`) to a user, telegram responds :

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Error: Wrong file identifier specified"}
```

this is the `sendPhoto` request :

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot1111111:AAG2kyktWYTwHEVL156YYJb-yiFvd4/sendPhoto?chat_id=22222&photo=AgADBAADeagxGzgMngUmjMxAoGC-v5SAcjAABHd8t3Qaw6LuQpsAAg1
```

This request works fine with one Bot, but not for the other Bot!

Does telegram restrict sending `file_id`s? so that the bots that are previously received that `file_id`s could only send them?!

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple
You cant send that fileId with another Bot. Every bot has their own fileId. It's not shared.

Another important thing is that you SHOULD hide your bot api key from that address!!

Comment: but I can send some `file_id`s that are not existed in that bot before! some `file_id`s works and most not work!

Comment: anyway how can I send a `file_id` that is valid on telegram servers to a user?!

Comment: its not possible for you to send a file_id(photo) with a bot while its sent to another bot. when you send this very photo to another bot, it will have different unique file_id.
If you want to send a photo you have two ways to do that with bots
1) upload that photo to telegram servers with bot
2) send that photo to your bot and get that file_id, then you can send that photo with that file_id **ONLY** with that bot.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Have Telegram a documentation about this subject?  or do you have any reference for this idea?

Answer (score 0):

Because each bot access to itself file stored on telegram and you are trying to use another file stored by an id.